# Adjusting Legend to Plot Spatial object in R (package sp)

Tags: r, plot, spatial

I am using package [sp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/sp.pdf) in R. I am plotting two variables in two Spatial objects using spplot function. What I want is to make the legend the same in both plots so that I can compare them. For example, using the following code, I want both plots have the same legend ranging from 5 (with the red color) to 40 (with the blue color). This is to compare these two plots. Here is the code and the plot.

```
library(sp)
data(meuse)
data(meuse.grid)
coordinates(meuse) <- c("x", "y")
coordinates(meuse.grid) <- c("x", "y")
gridded(meuse.grid) <- TRUE
col=colorRampPalette(c("red","blue"))(30)
meuse.grid@data$var.1=sample(11:40,length(meuse.grid@data[,1]),replace=TRUE)
meuse.grid@data$var.2=sample(5:30,length(meuse.grid@data[,1]),replace=TRUE)

p1=spplot(meuse.grid, "var.1", col.regions=col)
p2=spplot(meuse.grid, "var.2", col.regions=col)
print(p1, position = c(0,.5,.5,1),more=T)
print(p2, position = c(.5,.5,1,1),more=F)
```

[image]

Comment: Really, it's a little silly to reprint the same scale; it'd make more sense to do something along the lines of `ggplot2::facet_wrap`/`facet_grid`.

Comment: It is needed sometimes ... Take my word ... compare my reputation with yourself on stats.stackexchange :)

Comment: Why? After you've got the palette the same, you're printing the same thing twice in a single, comparative plot. It's more a matter of concision of design than stats.

Comment: Well ... I put them here together to just make my question clear ... but what if you want them separately ... say in a two different slide's presentation and want to compare them ... then you need them to be on the same scale ... Try to look beyond what you just see.

Comment: So my proposal worked for you?

Comment: It is working ... but not always! I found some problems with spplot and your proposal when the values to be plotted match the tick marks (i.e. the "at" argument) in colorkey. Then it does not color properly. To correct that, I think we need to first convert values to factor ... also min/max values in your asnwer should be extended to cover all values. It then works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
p1=spplot(meuse.grid, "var.1", col.regions=col, colorkey=list(at=seq(5, 30, 5), labels=as.character(seq(5, 30, 5))))
p2=spplot(meuse.grid, "var.2", col.regions=col, colorkey=list(at=seq(5, 30, 5), labels=as.character(seq(5, 30, 5))))
print(p1, position = c(0,.5,.5,1),more=T)
print(p2, position = c(.5,.5,1,1),more=F)
```

[image]